# How can I use MATCH for multiple rows in EXCEL?

Tags: excel, match, multiple-columns

I want to use something like the MATCH function in EXCEL, only that I want to look up a value in a table containing multiple rows and columns. The function should then return the column of the found value.

Here is a picture for better understanding:

[image: ExampleExcel]

In the cell K6 the value is "Chicken". I want to look up "Chicken" in the table that ranges from A1:G9. I then want to set the value in cell M6 to "Protein Source", as that is the associated value for "Chicken" in the table A1:G9.
Currently, there is the logical value "TRUE" in M6 because I used COUNTIF to see if "Chicken" is in A1:G9. But I don't know how to get the value "Protein Source" to M6.

MATCH would at least find the column/row number if I wouldn't have to look up multiple rows/columns. But MATCH doe not accept multiple rows/columns.

Comment: You are also going to need unique data in your reference table.  You have soya milk twice.  thankfully both under the same column, but if it were in different columns how do you determine which column would be the right answer

Comment: @Forward Ed: Soya Milk twice was unintentionally and is an error. Thanks, I removed the second soya milk!

Comment: @ForwardEd - Since there wasn't a hope in hell I was going to retype that sample data from the image, I actually missed that duplication!

Comment: @Jeeped I know what you mean and what you are getting at by screenshots versus example data.  I just happened to catch it before I retyped the whole thing!  wonder how many other retyped it?  Do you know if there is a movement afoot to add a feature that would allow you to copy paste tables into questions/answers?

Comment: @ForwardEd - Don't know if that was a tongue-in-cheek response but it's pretty simple to copy data directly from Excel into a code block. If the OP of a question can't get it right, many users with more editor experience (including myself) will take the time to format it properly so everyone has valid sample data.

Comment: @jeeped not tongue in cheek at all.  Speaking from my own experience and frustration.  I just want to be able to copy and past e my excel results in the question and it comes out horribly formatted, and then I feel embarrassed and or think how can anybody make heads or tails out of this garbage when I look at the preview.  So I then turn around and go the screen capture route.  Which while nicely formatted and looks pretty, does nothing to assist anyone from copying it into their own spreadsheets to "play with".

Comment: @jeeped As a regular user, I know people can edit and reformat and do all sorts of nice things.  As a new comer though, not knowing the ropes/environment,  it can be an intimidating barrier and the easiest way around it is to not post data at all,  next step is the screen capture.

Comment: @ForwardEd - The Data tab's Text-to-Columns command is in my QAT for all four versions of Excel that reside on my laptop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111312/discussion-between-forward-ed-and-jeeped).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=INDEX($A$1:$G$1,SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN($A$2:$G$9)*($A$2:$G$9=K3)))
```

Place that in M3 beside chicken and you should be able to copy it down.

So apologies but I could not do what you wanted with MATCH as per your question title.  However I could return the column number that your item was found in.  A major caveat to this equation is that whatever you are looking for in the A2:G9 range can only appear once! If it appears more than once, the equation may blow up on you or return an incorrect column even though there is no error.

Normally index and match work really well together.  You were trying to basically do:

```
=Index (header row, MATCH(Item I am looking for, Table of stuff))
```

So what I did was replace the Match part of that thought with SUMPRODUCT:

```
SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN($A$2:$G$9)*($A$2:$G$9=K3))
```

Basically what is going to happen is COLUMN will return the column number we are looking at for one instance of the calculation and then give the next column number as we work our way through the calculation.  Whatever that column number happens to be, get multiplied by a logic statement that is either 0 if false, or 1 if true.  So any column number that is does not have what we are looking for equates to 0, and only the column number that has what we are looking for is returned because it is multiplied by 1.

The pitfall is if you have chicken more than once, you will get column numbers more than once and they will be added together meaning for instance your soy milk which is in there twice in column 6 returns a value of 6+6 = 12.  The problem is we do not have 12 columns so we get an error.  Additionally if you had Banana twice, you would have had 1+1= 2 and you would have the header in the 2nd column of Vegetable returned.

[image: Proof of concept]

If you want to implement some potential error checking you could use some IFERROR and ERROR.TYPE in the equation.  It will not catch duplicates in column numbers.  You would wind up with something as follows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$G$1,SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN($A$2:$G$8)*($A$2:$G$8=K3))),IF(ERROR.TYPE(INDEX($A$1:$G$1,SUMPRODUCT(COLUMN($A$2:$G$8)*($A$2:$G$8=K3))))=3,"NOT FOUND","MULTIPLE ENTRIES"))
```

And then the results look something like this:

[image]

SIDE NOTE

On a side note, if your table was not in column A, your would need to subtract some number from the column equation such that the first column minus the magic number would result in 1...or you could do this to make it more dynamicish (that is the technical term right?):

```
SUMPRODUCT((COLUMN($A$2:$G$9)-COLUMN($A$2)+1)*($A$2:$G$9=K3))
```

Comment: Obviously not a zombie-friendly menu (although we might infer other meanings from the 'lack of brains')..

Comment: Thanks a lot! And thank you for your detailed explanation, it helped a lot for understanding the formula:)

Answer (score 3):

An [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/[MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) function pair that receives its column number from a series of [MATCH functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) may be suited to a standard formula based solution providing there are a limited number of rows. Each row would be examined with the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) passing control to the next MATCH statement if it is not found.

In M6 as a standard formula,

```
=INDEX(A$2:G$2, IFERROR(MATCH(K6, A$3:G$3, 0), IFERROR(MATCH(K6, A$4:G$4, 0),
                IFERROR(MATCH(K6, A$5:G$5, 0), IFERROR(MATCH(K6, A$6:G$6, 0),
                IFERROR(MATCH(K6, A$7:G$7, 0), IFERROR(MATCH(K6, A$8:G$8, 0),
                IFERROR(MATCH(K6, A$9:G$9, 0), MATCH(K6, A$10:G$10, 0)))))))))
```

[image: iferror_index_match]

This method seems suitable for your sample data but obviously has limitations as the number of rows of food data expands. If fact, at some point it may be expedient to cover columns A:G rather than rows 3:9.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to go about this is using Linq as a type of search method.

Is a great link to start!

Another way is looping through the rows and cells manually which is a slow nasty process and comparing the values.

I know you probably wanted a straight answer for your question but I think you would benefit more by using LINQ for what you want to do and keep it easy along with clean.

An easy Google search for "Use LINQ for excel" provides you many directions.

Example Links:

Using LINQ in Excel 2007
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920313(v=office.12).aspx

Video Linq to Excel for Data Search
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4aNwh7pRxo

Comment: Link only answers are generally frowned upon on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Provide narrative containing the substance of the article and use the link to point to auxiliary information.